# How to update updated_at when refresh the page in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-6, laravel-query-builder

I would like to update my column updated_at in database when I refresh the page what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

When you manage the petition, you'll be returning a view in some controller, just before that, `$the_model_you_want_to_update->setUpdatedAt($date)` if you want to update that to some specific value. This will update the value, every time the user enters the page.

Comment: I tried this... but didn't modificated all the rows of the table... I would like to update all the rows of the table and get the current time

Comment: it will act over all records you have in `$the_model_you_want_to_update` if you want to act the whole table, I guess 'Your_model::setUpdatedAt($date)' should work

Comment: Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::setUpdatedAt() should not be called statically I got this

Comment: One last try. Check `Your_model::all()->setUpdatedAt($date);`

Comment: Undefined variable: date

Comment: Well, `$date` should be the datetime you want to update it to

Answer (score 0):

just use Laravel Eloquent touch() method, for example `$user->touch();`

https://sarav.co/laravel-eloquent-touch